# How to optimize a SQL query with a multiple self-join?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have table Meetings in sql oracle

```
CREATE TABLE meetings ( 
meeting_id INTEGER,
 src INTEGER, 
 tgt INTEGER, 
start_date TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (meeting_id) 
);
```

And sample query:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(e idx_src) INDEX(f idx_src) INDEX(g idx_src) INDEX(h idx_src) INDEX(i idx_srct) */ 
COUNT(*)
FROM meetings e
JOIN meetings f ON e.tgt = f.src
JOIN meetings g ON f.tgt = g.src
JOIN meetings h ON g.tgt = h.src
JOIN meetings i ON h.tgt = i.src
WHERE e.src = 0;
```

It's just an example. I have around 99000 rows

Thats how explain plain for it looks like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |         |     1 |    36 |       | 38437   (8)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                          |         |     1 |    36 |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                              |         |   474M|    15G|  1552K| 38437   (8)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                  | IDX_SRC | 99090 |   387K|       |    58   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN                             |         |    15M|   487M|  1936K|  2396   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | E       | 99090 |   774K|       |   429   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      INDEX FULL SCAN                     | IDX_SRC | 99090 |       |       |   206   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |     HASH JOIN                            |         |   536K|    12M|       |   866   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      HASH JOIN                           |         | 18047 |   281K|       |   434   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| E       |   570 |  4560 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_SRC |   570 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| E       | 99090 |   774K|       |   429   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |        INDEX FULL SCAN                   | IDX_SRC | 99090 |       |       |   206   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | E       | 99090 |   774K|       |   429   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |       INDEX FULL SCAN                    | IDX_SRC | 99090 |       |       |   206   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to do indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_src ON meetings (src);
CREATE INDEX idx_tgt ON meetings (tgt);
```

But it only accelerated to 40 seconds

In general it takes 1 minute to complete. Please how can I optimize this to execute in 1 second?

Comment: Stop using the `A,B` join syntax. It's been obsolete for **more than 30 years** now.

Comment: Hi - first off I would learn ANSI SQL join syntax, which is easier to read/write/support than the syntax you are using and which hasn’t been good practice for 30+ years. Secondly, why have you created indexes on columns you aren’t using (person_one, person_two) rather than columns you are using (src , tgt )?

Comment: Oracle has its own syntax for hierarchical queries. I'd read the documentation on that; https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You have no starting condition (such as `ma` having to be a meeting with no parents). This man's that you're getting ***all*** combinations of 5 meetings. Imagine the case that meeting 1 has two children (11 and 12) and they each have two children (111, 112 and 121, 122) and so on for six levels (so meetings 111111 through to 122222), this query would return 16 rows with `ma=1` plus 16 rows where `ma=11` plus 16 rows where `ma=12` totalling 48 rows. What does that tell you? I strongly suggest you write a [mre] so we can give you a better query.

Comment: Case in point ; at one step, you're processing 15GB of data for 474 ***million*** combinations of meetings. I really don't think this query does what you think it does. It doesn't need optimising, it needs re-engineering.

Comment: @MatBailie how can I re-engineering it ?

Comment: By giving us example data and desired results (the [mre] link I gave you previously) and letting us form a better query for you. Because I'm not convinced this does what you think it does.

Comment: Read this too; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Stop working with 100,000 rows of data until you are sure that the query is correct. Work with 10 or 50 rows of data and calculate by hand what the answer should be and then check whether your query gives the same answer. Then check what happens if you change the data slightly (such as if you have multiple rows with the same `src` or `tgt` values) and work out by hand what you expect the result to be and then check your query gives the expected results. As pointed out, I think you will find that your query does not do what you expect but we can't help without a [MRE] with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want a hierarchical query rather than multiple self-joins:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   meetings
WHERE  LEVEL = 5
START WITH src = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR tgt = src
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE meetings ( 
  meeting_id INTEGER,
  src INTEGER, 
  tgt INTEGER, 
  start_date TIMESTAMP, 
  PRIMARY KEY (meeting_id) 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE meetings__meeting_id__seq;

INSERT INTO meetings (meeting_id, src, tgt)
SELECT meetings__meeting_id__seq.NEXTVAL,
       src,
       tgt
FROM   (
         SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS src,
                LEVEL     AS tgt
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
       )
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT LEVEL AS ignore FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
       )
```

Which creates 6 levels of the hierarchy and then duplicates the data 10 times giving a total of 60 rows.

Then the output of both your query and the hierarchical query is

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 100000 |

Since there are:

- 10 ways to pick the row for the first level of the hierarchy (your `e` table)
- 10 ways to pick the row for the second level of the hierarchy (your `f` table)
- 10 ways to pick the row for the third level of the hierarchy (your `g` table)
- 10 ways to pick the row for the fourth level of the hierarchy (your `h` table)
- 10 ways to pick the row for the fifth level of the hierarchy (your `i` table)

Which gives 10<sup>5</sup> = 10,000 possible combinations of paths from those 60 rows.

While the hierarchical query *may* speed up your results, it is also equally probable that the problem is the volume of data that is being generated as multiple child rows can correlate to multiple parent rows and as you descend the hierarchy the number of rows generated explodes exponentially.

If the count is 10,000 for only 60 rows of input then you can generate a huge amount of data for 99,000 rows of input; which you can see from your `EXPLAIN PLAN` as it generates 474,000,000 rows and 15Gb of data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J6vZDJAU)

Comment: Recursion takes even longer for some reason. But I also noticed that the data in my query is sometimes repeated, so if I don't take it into account when calculating, I do in the result. Then it will be a success

And data looks like:
```
INSERT INTO meetings VALUES (0, 0, 1, some_date);
INSERT INTO meetings VALUES (1, 0, 2, some_date); 
...
INSERT INTO meetings VALUES (21, 1, 1, some_date); 
INSERT INTO meetings VALUES (22, 1, 2, some_date); 
...
```
While calculating it will looks like 0->1->2->... 
And also 0->2->...

Comment: @NormalVector I'm simpler words; if you're getting unwanted repeated data, your query is wrong. Creating a [mre] will help us fix your query for you. There's no point trying to optimise something that's wrong.